# Travel Time using Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-directions-api

I want to get travel time betweeen two locations using Google API. I have already spent a couple of hours in sorting this out but no results yet. How do I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far? What kind of *travel time* do you need? Is it using the Directions service?

Comment: Did you have a look at the `DirectionsService` class ([see here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService))?

Answer (score 1):

The Distance Matrix API can get you travel time pretty easily. The documentation for the web services (HTTP interface) gives [an example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/).

You can also use the [Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) if you'd prefer that. There's another example at the bottom of the page.

If you want travel time in current traffic, you'll need a Google Maps for Business license.

Comment: is Distance Matrix API a free service?